# Spring Security OAuth2 JWT CORS not allowed

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a trouble with CORS configuration. I've followed few tutorials, videos on YT and I was looking for help here, on StackOverflow - but nothing helps me.
I have two backend projects (first one - Spring Boot 1.5.9 with OAuth2 and JWT, second one - Spring Boot 2.0.0 M7 with Spring Security 5 basic authentication) and my friend uses React for frontend. In both I have the same problem - when we want to login, server responses with 401 HTTP status and following message:
`Failed to load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401`

**Case 1 (Spring Boot 1.5.9 OAuth2 JWT)**

In this project I have

> SecurityConfig class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
>
> My implementation of AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
>
> And implementation of ResourceServerConfig

My ResourceServerConfig class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCES_IDS = "ResourceId";
private static final String SECURITY_REALM = "Spring Boot Realm";

private final TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
public ResourceServerConfig(TokenStore tokenStore) {
    this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCES_IDS)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(REGISTER_USER + "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, GEOTAGS_PATH + "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .realmName(SECURITY_REALM)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().cors();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final TokenStore tokenStore;
private final JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public AuthorizationServerConfig(TokenStore tokenStore,
                                 JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter,
                                 AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                 @Qualifier("customDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    this.accessTokenConverter = accessTokenConverter;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer
            .jdbc(dataSource);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    final TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Collections.singletonList(accessTokenConverter));
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
            .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }
}
```

And finally SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String SIGNING_KEY = "Gz73RSOADKDFXzONqg3q";

private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void setCustomUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
    this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
}

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("customDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(SIGNING_KEY);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

    return source;
   }

}
```

As you can see I use CorsConfigurationSource Bean but when we run javascript code which is in different Origin:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': `Basic ${window.btoa('eTaxiClientId:secret')}`
},
body: `username=${encodeURIComponent('Admin')}&password=${encodeURIComponent('pass')}&grant_type=password`
});
```

Server response with message that I described on the beginning.

I have also tried use my implementation of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter with overridden addCorsMappings method, I tried to permitAll HttpMethod.OPTIONS but browser always sends OPTIONS request witch is matched with 401 code.

**Case 2 (Spring Boot 2)**

In this project I tried to use basic Spring Security authorization system - without OAuth2 and JWT. And my configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final DataSource dataSource;

public SecurityConfig(MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                      @Qualifier("customDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .servletApi().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/1").hasAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers("/api/2").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/3").hasAuthority("GUEST")
            .and()
            .anonymous().principal("guest").authorities("GUEST")
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository())
            .and()
            .headers()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
 //                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

    return source;
}
```

}

And in this case when we run following code in JavaScript application:

```
  const body = `username=${encodeURIComponent('admin')}&password=${encodeURIComponent('pass')}`;

const hashedCredentials = btoa('admin:pass');

return axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`, body, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        // test oauth credentials
        Authorization: `Basic ${hashedCredentials}`
    }
})
    .then(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', hashedCredentials);
})
.then(() => {
    const userCredentials = localStorage.getItem('user');

return axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/2`, null, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${userCredentials}`
    }
});
}).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

OPTIONS request passes and we have status 200 response but as you can see we tried to redirect user to end point that is protected. But instead of displaying message on the screen, Spring Security redirects as to login page..

**Summary**

Have someone had such problem? Does someone see what we are doing wrong ? Why do we have problem in both projects? Is better (and safer) approach for user authentication?

I hope I haven't forgotten to describe something and I am looking forward for response. Cheers !